# Is rsync's --link-dest option "better" than --backup-dir?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, mirroring, incremental-backup

In his popular article [Easy Automated Snapshot-Style Backups with Linux and Rsync](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/#Incremental), Mike Rubel asserts that using `rsync` to create hard-linked snapshots with `--link-dest` is "a better way" to perform incremental backups than using `--backup-dir`, but he does not explain this statement.

I'm hoping to using `rsync` to create daily backups of about 1-2 GB of personal data from my laptop's `$HOME` directory. I would like a mirror of the current state of my files, plus some way to recover older versions of files (so I guess I want incremental backups).

What did Mike Rubel mean when he called his solution better than `--backup-dir`? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each solution? Which might be better for my situation?

Edit: I should clarify that the total size of the full backup would be 1-2 GB. Likely there will only be a few MB (or less) of new data each day. And I plan to back up to a local storage drive.

Comment: I believe --link-dest is the go-to command for taking incremental backups because you only take a full backup once, and after that you only backup files that have changed. With --backup-dir I believe you do a full backup each time.

Comment: Even when used with `-b` (`--backup`)? The article states that using `-b --backup-dir=` is the most common way (at the time the article was written) to perform incremental backups.

Comment: @Bungicasse sorry, forgot to tag you